# How to tell which module has requested memory with request_mem_region?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm writing a kernel driver which needs to access memory-mapped IO.

My call to `request_mem_region` is failing, indicating that another module (either loaded or built-in) has requested the memory in question.

How can I determine which driver has done this?

Seeing as a string identifier is passed to the `request_mem_region` function, I assume this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`/proc/iomem`](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-iomem.html) is a file that shows the current map of the system's memory for each physical device.